# Failed to find Linux Kernel Module

Tags: systemd, kernel-modules

I`m trying to add driver for specific hardware at startup.

Module file is located at `/lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/`.
Also I've tried `/lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/`.

Module is successfully loaded with command:

```
$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/misc/tmk1553b.ko d0=1 t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1
```

But couldn’t load module at startup.

Configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2

```
$ uname -a
Linux dmitry-ws2 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

tmk1553b d0=1 t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1
```

Made command:

```
$ depmod
```

After restarting computer or service systemd-load-module module `tmk1553b` doesn’t appear into loaded kernel modules list.

Diagnostic returns `Failed to find module "tmk1553b ..."` error.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service 
Job for systemd-modules-load.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service 
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Чт 2017-03-30 11:22:17 MSK; 25s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 3971 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3971 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

```
$ journalctl -xe
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 sudo[3968]:   dmitry : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=XXX; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 sudo[3968]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dmitry(uid=0)
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита systemd-modules-load.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Процесс остановки юнита systemd-modules-load.service был завершен.
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита systemd-modules-load.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита systemd-modules-load.service.
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd-modules-load[3971]: Failed to find module 'tmk1553b d0="1" t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1'
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мар 30 11:22:17 dmitry-ws2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита systemd-modules-load.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Произошел сбой юнита systemd-modules-load.service.
-- 
-- Результат: failed.
```

What is going wrong?

UPDATE 1:

```
$ cat /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/modules.dep | grep tmk1553b
kernel/drivers/misc/tmk1553b.ko:
```

`modprobe` command returns with success

```
$ sudo modprobe tmk1553b d0=1 t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1
```

UPDATE 2:

Actions I made during driver installation:

```
$ cp tmk1553b.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/misc/
$ echo tmk1553b d0=1 t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1 >> /etc/modules
$ depmod
$ reboot
```

This sequence works well on Ubuntu 14.04 but fails on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: Solution found: systemd-modules-load could not divide module name and options. Module options must be specified in /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf

Comment: Please don't edit the solution in your question. If a given answer solved your problem, accept it, you can add more information in comments under the answer. If none of the given answers solved your problem you can answer your own question. Only accepting an answer will mark your question as "solved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigations revealed that systemd is unable to load modules with options. Solution worked for me:

- place module name to `/etc/modules`
- place module options to `/etc/modprobe.d/options-tmk1553b.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/modules
tmk1553b
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/options-tmk1553b.conf
options tmk1553b d0=1 t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1
```

Seems this is common behavior for linux distributions with `systemd` init system

Answer (score 2):

In order to be loaded successfully at boot time, your module should be loadable using `modprobe` instead of `insmod`. You can try using:

```
modprobe tmk1553b d0=1 t0="MRTAI" nrt=8 misc=1
```

Running `sudo depmod` is necessary after installing the module under the path `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`. You can confirm this looking for your module file in the file:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep
```

Comment: `modprobe` works well, module tmk1553b present in modules.dep. See update 1